# array_keys error while running artisan basset

Tags: php, laravel

I am receiving the proceeding error exception when I run `php artisan basset --tidy-up` from the command line.

```
[ErrorException] 
array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

basset [--delete-manifest] [--tidy-up]
```

I was unfortunate in finding any details online.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not used Basset, the reason for this error is that you are passing in an object, rather than an array, for the first argument of [array_keys](http://www.php.net/array_keys).

For example, were I to have an array as follows:

```
$myGreatArray = array('first' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'sup');
```

And then pass it in to array keys:

```
print_r(array_keys($myGreatArray));
```

I'd get this as the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => bar
)
```

However, I can't do the same thing with an object, even if it's structured the same way.

In other words, we can't do something like this (and not just because you need to var_dump objects, but also because you need to pass in arrays to array_keys()):

```
$myGreatArray = new stdClass;
$myGreatArray->first = 'foo';
$myGreatArray->bar = 'sup';
print_r(array_keys($myGreatArray));
```

You'll get an error similar to what you're seeing, although what you're seeing appears to be in a format of an [exception](http://php.net/exceptions) handled by Basset. You can also see it when running a script from other than the command line, depending on your level of [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Edit:

I just pulled up the source for [Basset's command line script](https://github.com/jasonlewis/basset/blob/master/src/Basset/Console/BassetCommand.php), and it looks like you're getting the error on [line 120](https://github.com/jasonlewis/basset/blob/master/src/Basset/Console/BassetCommand.php#L120), which reads as follows:

```
$collections = array_keys($this->environment->all()) + array_keys($this->manifest->all());
```

You might want to check the way your manifest and environment are structured.